# Webkit pseudo elements don't respect SVG mask

Tags: css, svg, webkit, mask

I've made this SVG mask:

```
<svg width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 1 1" style="position: absolute;pointer-events: none;top: -1px;left: -1px;width: 1px;height: 1px;">
<mask id="custom-mask" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"></rect>
    <circle fill="black" cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.2"></circle>
</mask>
 </svg>
```

It's just a small circle cut from the center. Now if I use this mask using a foreignObject:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
            <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#custom-mask)" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <div class="block">
                     SOME CONTENT
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
     </svg>
```

The hole in the middle is visible but if `class="block"` has a pseudo element, Webkit doesn't keep the hole but Firefox does.

```
.block
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.block:after
{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: (open it in both Firefox and Chrome and see the difference)
https://jsfiddle.net/Lqctwymb/1/

Is there a way to make this work in Webkit-based browsers?

Comment: Well they are open source so you could always download the source code to the browsers and fix it yourself. That's what I've been doing with Firefox.

Comment: Use `<g>` instead of `<div>` inside the SVG and add `.block::after { z-index: -1 }` to see the text with a red background... Oh, and it is *pseudo* not *sudo*. `sudo` is a Unix command.

Comment: @RenevanderLende Settings z-index to -1, just hides it. I want to see the mask hole on the pseudo element.